# Create a dynamic changing name of a name range in excel

Tags: excel, vba

i'm looking for a way to Create a dynamic changing name of a name range in excel.
for example:

```
A1 = "John"
A2 = 32
A3 = "st.lo"
```

now i want the name of the range A1:A3 will be "John"
Note that the value of A1 can change to another value lets say:

```
A1 = "michele"
```

now i want that the name of the range A1:A3 will change to "michele" (Automaticly).
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use in the event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
```

This Code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names(Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Name.Name).Name = Range("A1").Value
```

Everytime you change the name of cell A1, the macro change the name of the Range...
I explain: Take directly the name of the range from the Cell "A1" :

```
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Name.Name
```

and from the collection of name of Range:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names(
```

change the name with the new value of "A1":

```
).Name
```

OK ?

For every Range:
Inside your macro:

```
For Each xx In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    CellRange = Cells(Range(xx.Value).Row, Range(xx.Value).Column)
    xx.Name = CellRange
Next
```

Pay attention to DON'T have two cells with the same name. The name of range SHALL be unique...
Explain: For every RangeName in the Workbook I take (2° row) the value of the first cell that give me the name for the Range. After I change the name ...

Comment: thanks but sory but i don't understand that code verry well. i'm creating an event that will run on any change of the worksheet... but how does it changes the range? where are the refference and where is the actual range?

Comment: worked like a charm.
i'm not that good in vba so i had troubles using an event so i just used it as public sub and manualy ran the macro. works great thanks man!

Comment: Can i loop through all the ranges in a sheet and change their names as the value of the first cell in every range?